# Why does EVP_VerifyInit fail for common digest types in FIPS mode in OpenSSL 3?

Tags: openssl

I'm enabling FIPS mode in OpenSSL3 in a legacy code and I ran into a problem that can be reproduced using a simple C++ program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "openssl/evp.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

const char *openssl_error()
{
    return ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr);
}

int main()
{
    if (!EVP_default_properties_enable_fips(nullptr, 1))
    {
        printf("Failed to enable FIPS: %s\n", openssl_error());
        return -1;
    }

    auto ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx)
    {
        printf("Failed to make CTX: %s\n", openssl_error());
        return -1;
    }

    if (!EVP_VerifyInit(ctx, EVP_sha256()))
    {
        printf("Failed to start verification: %s\n", openssl_error());
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Everything looks OK.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

After compilation the program fails with the error:

```
Failed to start verification: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

If I don't enable FIPS mode with `EVP_default_properties_enable_fips`, the program ends normally.

Why does this API fail?

Other things I tried:

- I tried using EVP_sha1() and EVP_sha384() as digest type, the same failure occurs.
- I tried calling EVP_VerifyInit_ex() with nullptr as engine, the same failure occurs.

OpenSSL3 is built in house by some other team, so it's entirely possible there is a configuration problem somewhere, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: To use FIPS in OpenSSL 3, you must both (1) load the FIPS provider, which can be done either with configuration or (mostly) in code AND (2) select relevant algorithms from the FIPS provider, which again can be done either in configuration or in code. You did 2b -- (try to) select FIPS using code -- but show no evidence of either 1a or 1b. See [manpage fips_module(7)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/fips_module.html).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Oh, I thought it's just a toggle, now it seems the product needs to carry around an extra .so/.dll to use it.